# jQuery push to multi-dimensional array returns only the last value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a multi-dimensional array but for some reason only the last value is returned instead of a 10-items array.

```
let a = [];

$.each(IDs, function(index, value) {
    let au = $('#' + value + '.comment .user-name').text();
    let av = $('#' + value + '.comment .profile-pic').attr('src');
    let l = $('#' + value + '.comment .likes-count').text();
    let arr = [value, au, av, l];

    a.push = (arr);
});
console.log(a);
```

Output in console:

```
[push: Array(4)]
push: (4) ["99", "John Baker", "template/images/avatars/fav3.svg", "20"]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `a.push = (arr);`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` is a array *method* but you are using it (assigning value) as if it is a *property* of the array.

Change

```
a.push = (arr);
```

To

```
a.push(arr);
```

Comment: Gosh... don't know how I missed that. Will mark as the correct answer. Thank you sir.